# Socketcan Driver implementation

Tags: c, embedded-linux, yocto, socketcan

I am new to creating a driver implementing.
My Application is using socketcan interface and apparently socketcan is not supported by the SOC.
I am planning to write my own driver. The issue I know how simple module for kernel I am not pretty sure where to start for socketcan driver .
If someone can please tell me where can I take reference for building the CAN driver or some git repo where can I use it and any specifics while writing the driver

Answer (score 0):

SocketCan is the name of a Linux subsystem. It can be enabled in the kernel config via `CONFIG_CAN`. In turn, this subsystem will make use of platform-specific drivers to control the SOC's CAN adapters (if any).

If Linux's CAN subsystem is not enabled, make sure to enable `CONFIG_CAN`. If it *is* enabled, and no "can" device show up, the best would likely be to contact the SOC vendor for further guidance / drivers / devicetree / ... In any case, writing a custom driver is probably not necessary here.